# How to make a button that will send only send values from one table to a row in another table if another cell has a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried google but I can't seem to get the right answer as I am inexperienced with `VBA`.

I am trying to copy row 3, with the click of a button, into the last row of a table that is found further down on the same sheet. More specifically, the first data will go into `B13:O13`

Upon, the click of the button, the following will occur. Data from B3 to D3 will go to B13 to D13. Data from E3, F3, G3, H3 & I3 will be combined into E13. Data from H3 to N3 will go to J13 to N13. So far I was able to find the answer for that on this website, in [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/585687/how-to-make-a-button-that-will-send-all-values-from-one-table-to-a-row-in-anothe)

However, the issue is with O13, I'd like to copy the data in O13 ONLY if C3 has the text "Company" in it (without quotation marks). If O13 says other than "Company", I'd like only columns B3 to N3 to be copied.

Unfortunately, conditional formatting of the table itself in attempt to achieve this did not work, as O3 changes fill color depending on whether B3 says "Company" or not, which overrides any conditional formatting for fill colors in the table I may have, once the O3 is copied into the last row of the table.

Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Please help me create the conditional code for O3. Here is the code I have used so far for copying B3 to N3, which I have posted in the Module section:

Option Explicit

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
```

define which worksheet to work on, i.e. replace Sheet1 with the name of your sheet

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1. Clients Details")
```

determine the last row with content in column A and add one

```
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

copy some cells into their ranges

```
ws.Range("B3:D3").Copy ws.Range("B" & lRow)
ws.[B1].Select
```

combine E3, F3, G3, H3 and I3 and copy into column E, next empty row

```
ws.Range("E" & lRow) = ws.[E3] & " " & ws.[F3] & " " & ws.[G3] & ", " & ws.[H3] & " " & ws.[I3]
```

copy the other cells into their ranges

```
ws.Range("J3:N3").Copy ws.Range("J" & lRow)
ws.[J1].Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your check:

```
if Worksheets("yourWorksheet").Range("C3").Value like "*""Company""*" then
    'do something
else
    'do something else
end if
```

Comment: Hi avb,
Thanks alot for your answer. It solved the problem. I hand to change your code to the below code to make it work.

if Worksheets("yourWorksheet").Range("C3").Value like "Company" then
    'do something
else
    'do something else
end if

Thanks again. You fixed my spreadsheet!

Comment: Is there a way to give your answer a like or increase your score or mark this query as answered. I'm new to this.